# Using NSMutableArray to change switch cases. Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a `NSMutableArray` with an array of numbers with which I'd like to change cases in `switch`. And all the variables declared. And no matter what I try, the application always crashes.
What should I do to pass an `int` from array to `switch`?

```
 -(NSMutableArray*)tasks {
     tasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:2] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:3] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:4] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:5] ,.........,nil];
     return tasks;
     }

- (IBAction)random:(id)sender {
    text = [[tasks objectAtIndex:x] integerValue];
    x++;

        switch (text) {


            case 0:
               //something
                break;

            case 1:
                //something
                break;

            case 2:
                //something
                break;
.
.
.
.
.
            case 22:
               //something
                break;   
            default:

        }  }
```

Comment: `tasks = @[@1, @2 ...]`

Comment: What does the crash say ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this ? It should work.

```
-(NSMutableArray*) tasks {
    NSMutableArray *tasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:2] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:3] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:4] ,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:5],nil];
    return tasks;
}

- (IBAction)random:(id)sender {
    int x = 0;
    NSInteger text = [[self.tasks objectAtIndex:x] integerValue];
    x++;

    switch (text) {


        case 0:
            //something
            break;

        case 1:
            //something
            break;

        case 2:
            //something
            break;
        case 22:
            //something
            break;
        default:
            ;

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this may be the problem as @Barry has pointed out! Unless you use self.tasks, the property method doesn't get called.